# How does SELinux affect the /home directory?

Tags: centos, postgresql, selinux

I'm migrating a CentOS 5.3 system from MySQL to PostgreSQL.  The way our machine is set up is that the biggest disk partition is mounted to `/home`.  This is out of my control and is managed by the hosting provider.  Anyway, we obviously want the database files to be on `/home` for this reason.

With MySQL, we did the following:

- Edited `my.cnf` and changed the `datadir` setting to `/home/mysql`
- Added a new "File type" policy record (I hope I'm using the right terminology) to set `/home/mysql(/.*)?` to `mysqld_db_t`
- Ran `restorecon -R /home/mysql` to assign the labels

and everything was good.

With PostgreSQL, however, I did the following:

- Edited `/etc/init.d/postgresql` and changed the `PGDATA` and `PGLOG` variables to `/home/pgsql/data` and `/home/pgsql/pgstartup.log`, respectively
- Added a new policy record to set `/home/pgsql/pgstartup.log` to `postgresql_log_t`
- Added a new policy record to set `/home/pgsql/data(/.*)?` to `postgresql_db_t`
- Ran `restorecon -R /home/pgsql` to assign the labels

At this point, I still cannot start PostgreSQL.  pgstartup.log says:

```
# cat pgstartup.log
postmaster cannot access the server configuration file "/home/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

The weird thing is that I don't see any messages related to this in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/secure`, **but** if I turn off SElinux, then everything works.

I made sure all the permissions are correct (600 for files and 700 for directories), as well as the ownership (postgres:postgres).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I'm using the Yum repository from [commandprompt.com](https://projects.commandprompt.com/public/pgcore/), version 8.3.7.

**EDIT:**  The reason my question specifically mentions the `/home` directory is that if I go through all these steps for any other directory, e.g. `/var/lib/pgsql2` or `/usr/local/pgsql`, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This thread looks relevant - http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2007-11/msg00228.php.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.  Unfortunately, it looks like I am already doing exactly what I am supposed to -- namely, changing the SELinux policy to allow PostgreSQL to access the specific directories I need.  Furthermore, the steps I took *do* work, for any place other than a directory in /home.

Answer (score 1):

First check the label on the conf file. Poking around on a Centos5.3 system I see

```
semanage fcontext -l | grep "postgresql_etc_t"
/etc/postgresql(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:postgresql_etc_t:s0
```

and policy says

```
sesearch -A -s postgresql_t -t postgresql_etc_t
Found 3 av rules:
allow postgresql_t postgresql_etc_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock }; 
allow postgresql_t postgresql_etc_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search }; 
allow postgresql_t postgresql_etc_t : lnk_file { read getattr };
```

try to do an

```
ls -Z /home/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

If the label isn't right there are various ways to change it. A quick google gave me http://docs.fedoraproject.org/selinux-user-guide/f10/en-US/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html

semanage is one way. If you want to try to do a quick test try

```
chcon -t postgresql_etc_t /home/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Also make sure that the postgresql daemon is running in the right domain (ie SELinux context). You might quickly find that it is not by tailing the logs, see below. see run_init for details on kicking off an init script so that it is in the right domain. posgresql might be running as unconfined_t (in which case there shouldn't be a problem, unconfined gets to do a lot).

There may be other issues with SELinux for further analysis try tailing the audit log. (note that the audit log isn't written to until auditd is up, I've been bitten by that before. In that case check /var/log/messages for pre auditd log messages)

Try and see what SELinux might be complaining about

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

or to look just for denials

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied
```

Then try the same access ie start the deamon.

Answer (score 0):

did u check out u r #SESTATUS

[root@yeswedeal ~]# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: Hi Rajat.  SELinux is enabled.

Comment: Hi Matt Solnit Production server normally  [root@yeswedeal ~]# sestatus SELinux status: disabled

it should be disabled

Comment: No, running without SELinux enabled on a production server is a BAD idea.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have labeled the directories correctly, it is quite possible that the selinux policy forbids postgresql from acessing `/home` itself (the link mentioned in @Milen's answer, in fact, seems to imply that).

Comment: Hi CesarB.  I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that SELinux treats /home as a special case, even if I label it correctly?  That certainly sounds like what I'm seeing, but I didn't see anything in Milen's link that refers to /home.